# How to remove margin between centered input search tag and select tag

Tags: html, css, tags

Im having trouble removing the space between a centered input type="search" and a drop down select tag.
Here the html and css im using

```
<div id="div" align="center">
<input id="search" type="search" >
<span id="span">
<select>
<option value="all">All Catigories</option>
<option value="test1">Test 1</option>
<option value="test2">Test 2</option>
<option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select>
</span>
</div>

div {
margin: 0;
}
input {
margin: 0;
}
select {
margin: 0;
padding-left:0;
}
```

Heres a JSFiddle I made
https://jsfiddle.net/ayt9q75e/1/

Comment: i made a bit of change to your code but it's coming to the left hand side will it be ok like that?

Comment: @Swordys, it will not work

Answer (score 1):

`If I understand you properly :`https://jsfiddle.net/ayt9q75e/3/

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
input {
    display: inline-block;

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div id="div" align="center">
<input id="search" type="search" >
<span id="span">
<select>
<option value="all">All Catigories</option>
<option value="test1">Test 1</option>
<option value="test2">Test 2</option>
<option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select>
</span>
</div>
```

```
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
select {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, obviously there are line-breaks between each line.

With HTML a line-break belongs to "white-spaces", so it's rendered as a space.

You have to suppress those line-breaks to get what you want:

```html
<div id="div" align="center">
<input id="search" type="search" ><span id="span"><select>
<option value="all">All Catigories</option><option value="test1">Test 1</option>
<option value="test2">Test 2</option>
<option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select></span>
</div>
```

Note that you don't need anything like `margin: 0` any more.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ayt9q75e/2

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div" align="center">
   <input id="search" type="search"><span id="span">
      <select>
         <option value="all">All Catigories</option>
         <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
         <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
         <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
      </select>
   </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
   margin: 0;
}
input {
   margin: 0;
   display: inline-block;
}
#span {
   display: inline-block;
}
select {
   margin: 0;
   padding-left:0;
}
```

**Important:** remove the line break before <span id="span">

And I recommend to use CSS to center the div content instead of align="center"

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way add a class to the parent div and set `font-size:0;` this will fix your problem

```
div {
  font-size:0;
}
```